# Install XCode on a remote machine using script

Tags: install, xcode, mac-appstore

I'm new to Apple development. As per my understanding, in order to build IOS apps, we require Xcode. I installed and tried out some builds also in a Mac machine.

Now, I'm setting up CI/CD pipeline for an IOS app using Flutter and GitLab. In order to set up Runner, I need to install Xcode on the runner machine. I was looking for a script to install XCode and set up the runner.

Is that doable? For manual installation, I need to sign in with an Apple id for code download. As it requires authentication, how can I satisfy my requirement?

Comment: If as a one-off I would just use Screen Sharing from the remote machine to your local one.

Comment: The implementation of this simple to state problem is quite complicated. You can take advantage of a tool called mas on 10.12 and lower to fully automate most installs. I’ve not tried it on Xcode. https://github.com/mas-cli/mas/issues/164 - do you need one version specifically of macOS?

Comment: Good luck in setting up your CI/CD server. To my experience building an app with Xcode is not a big problem, but when it comes to signing the problems really starts: Xcode relies on the MacOS key chain system which is not designed to be used without UI and not from within a service that runs without logged-in user. All workarounds always need manual configuration and only hold until the used certificate expires or Apple changes.